# EF Fluent generated entities and default values - again

Tags: entity-framework

My question is, am I doing somethig wrong or is this somethig that is brioken in Entity Framework

Using both : EF DbContext Fluent Generator and Reverse Engineer Coder First no handling of default values.  Whay afre the delfault not being configured.  Isd there soke trick I a missing to mae this work?

It seems to me that if I generate code fluently from an existing database, and I have columns with pre-set default values, that the generated code should handle setting those default values.  I have this nice Model that i can look at in the designer, all the tables and relationships yet all my columns properties for default values are blank.  Why should i have to manually hand code thousands of default values, yes thousands.  Hundreds of tales times many columns.  Every single column in our database has defined default values.  The generated code should do whatever it needs to do to set those default values for me. Isn't that the point of using the tool, do make things less work?

When I use the NHibernate fluent generators, they handle default values. Why is there a difference between the two frameworks with respect to defaults?

Is there another tool available that can hack these in saving me weeks of work?

Comment: try to revise your question. :)

Comment: Revised, anything else ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't.

Slightly longer answer: The current accepted solution is to redundantly specify defaults in constructors. The only alternative is to declare properties as database-generated, but then you can't update them, so it's really only useful for timestamping or ID generation.

You may search for other similar questions properly and to find more explanations.

Also see [this UserVoice suggestion](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2929682-support-database-default-values-in-code-first).